# JQuery Datatable - Trigger Paging Event

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to call a function while doing pagination in JQUERY Datatable. I placed the below code in document ready

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$('#example').on( 'page.dt', function () {
  alert('Paging Clicked');
} );
```

But somehow it is not working. Also, i am not getting any script errors.

Comment: As you can see by yourself in the [doc example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) it works.

Comment: You are not specifying event param for [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method and what is this `page.dt` ?

Comment: I have googled it. There i saw one response, saying that page.dt is working for pagination event. So i have tried that.  But i don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Have a look at this [Example](http://live.datatables.net/yavikiqo/1/edit). its working here.

Comment: i have changed like this 'alert( 'page change' );' and tried...Still nothing got triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Initially i was placing the directly in document ready. After that i have tried like this, and it is working fine.

```
function JQueryChildDatatable() {
        var dtChildTable = $('#dtChild').dataTable({
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "paging": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
         });

        $('#dtChild').on( 'page.dt', function () {
           alert('Page Clicked');
        });
    }
```